# jQuery DataTables ordering by sets within rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable created with an `<asp:Repeater>` to create a table that looks like this (note: headers/data here are arbitrary):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>USA</div>
            <div>Canada</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Marc Anthony</div>
            <div>Cleopatra</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>JUL-10-1990</div>
            <div>DEC-22-1045</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- multiple data rows like the one above; always USA/Canada, but different names DOBs -->
</table>
```

What I need to be able to do is, when clicking on a column (Name or DOB) to sort it, alternate sorting the column by the first data set (first `<div>` data in a row) or second data set (second `<div>` data in a row). i.e. First click orders by `[USA]-[Marc Anthony]-[JUL-10-1990]` set, second click orders by `[Canada]-[Cleopatra]-[DEC-22-1045]` set, but maintains each set in the `<tr>` structure.

I don't need to use a repeater, I can use a JSON datasource a la:

```
$(...).DataTable(
    data: [JSON object]
);
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this by reading the [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) manual/API/whatever with group sets or whatnot. Can anyone help?

I am not married to the current structure, I can manipulate it pretty much however I want as long as it maintains the 'look' of grouped sets in each row.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into it right now, but a couple links on the DataTables website which might be helpful that I wasn't aware of before: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/, https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort

Comment: @Adam awesome, thank you, I'll look into those and post an answer (crediting you :D) if I find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 parts to this. The bigger one is the custom sorting, followed by a smaller one to detect whether to sort by the first or second div.

Datatables provides documentation on some custom sort plugins, but it's easy to create your own from looking at their [examples](https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort). Basically what I am doing here is creating a custom sort plugin called 'div-toggle'.

For the solution I've come up with, it would be easiest if you add classes to the divs in your data, like this:

```
 <td>
    <div class="firstDiv">USA</div>
    <div class="secondDiv">Canada</div>
 </td>
```

To do what you want, you'll need to add a custom sorting plugin that parses the data in each row and then decides whether to return the data contained in the first  or second . This code generates a plugin into dataTables to do that:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['div-toggle'] = function (settings, col) {
    return this.api().column(col, { order: 'index' }).nodes().map(function (td, i) {
        var cellData;
        if (firstDiv) cellData = $($(td).html()).find('.firstDiv').text();
        else cellData = $($(td).html()).find('.secondDiv').text();
        return cellData;
    });
}
```

The way I'm approaching it here, "firstDiv" is a boolean global variable which tells the plugin whether to use the first or second div when sorting. You could apply an event listener to the header being clicked for toggling this value:

```
$('.dataTable').on('click', 'thead tr th:eq(0)', function () {
    if (firstDiv) firstDiv = false;
    else firstDiv = true;
});
```

To tell dataTables to use this sorting plugin on a particular column, add the declaration into the "columns" attribute on initialization:

```
$(...).DataTable(
    { 
        "columns" : [ {"orderDataType": "div-toggle"} ]
    }
);
```

This would be for applying this sorting plugin to a dataTable with only one column, just to give you an idea of how to use it.

**Please note**: There are undoubtedly better selectors you could use in my example code and likely a more efficient way to do the sort parsing, but this code should work and give you a good base to start from to make it work even better.